# show and hide children widget of multiple parent widget

Tags: flutter

I have comments and comment replies of post. I want to display reply of comment on button click of their respective parent widget.

The code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.length; i++) {
                                      bool a=false;
                                         return Container(

                                                     rest of code...

                                                          TextButton(
                                                              onPressed: () {
                                                               
                    if (snapshot.data![i].comments![j].reply!.isNotEmpty && !a) {
                                                                  setState(() {
                                                                    a=!a;
                                                                  });
                                                                 print("if block ");
                                                                 print(a);
                                                                } else {
                                                                  setState(() {
                                                                    a=!a;                                                                  });
                                                            print("else block ");
                                                            print(a);
                                                                }
                                                              },
                                                              child: Text("View Reply")),
 if(a)...[
                                                for(int k=0;k<snapshot.data![i].comments![j].reply!.length;k++)...[
                                                    Row(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                    children: [
                                                      IconButton(
                                                          iconSize: 50,
                                                          onPressed: () {},
                                                          icon: CircleAvatar(
                                                            radius: 80,
                                                            backgroundImage:
                                                                NetworkImage(snapshot.data![i].comments![j].reply![k].user.profile),
                                                          )),
                                                      Column(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .center,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Container(
                                                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -160,
                                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                  borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                                  color: Colors.grey[300]),
                                                              padding:
                                                                  EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                                              child: Column(
                                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                                  children: [
                                                                    Text(
                                                                      snapshot.data![i].comments![j].reply![k].user.name,
                                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                                          fontSize:18,
                                                                          color: Colors.black,
                                                                          fontWeight:FontWeight.bold),
                                                                    ),
                                                                    Text(
                                                                        snapshot.data![i].comments![j].reply![k].replyText,
                                                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize:16,color: Colors.grey[700])),
                                                                  ])
                                                                  ),
                                                        ])
                                                    ])
                                                          ]
                                                        ]
                                                        else...[
                                                          Text("not")
                                                        ]
)}
```

should I use List type with comment index .The comment reply is not showing,when I click the button of their parent widget.
How to make this happen and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you pass this through dart format please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visibility widget to show and hide widget.

Comment: I want to use conditionally...

Comment: Set the visible: false in Visibility when you want to hide ortherwise set true.

Comment: It shows and hide all comments reply on one button click,I want to  show and hide reply of single comment